# How to share keystrokes or mouse clicks between multiple instances of a program?

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent, keystroke

I'm currently busy with achieving something that I can't seem to understand.

Lets say I have 3 Notepad windows open on my screen. On the first one I start typing, how can I share the input with my other 2 Notepad windows and let them output exactly the same thing?

They **DON'T** need to be hidden, I prefer to have them opened in my screen, so lets say they are next to each other. I don't need code, but I need some kind of explanation how to achieve this. I've read about `SendInput()` and `SendMessage()`, but I don't get how they can send the right coordinates, for example mouse clicks at exactly the same place.

What I did so far is I made handles for all Notepad windows so they have exactly the same coordinates when active, but how can I share a left mouse button click across all of them with only 1 active window and the other 2 next to it?

Comment: You can install window hooks on the "master" process and deliver those events to the other processes, but for things like mouse input, it really depends on how Notepad and any underlying controls are responding to window messages.  You can fake the mouse position so that screen-to-client co-ordinate operations compensate for the different window position, but if anything in the program is pulling mouse position from Windows API calls instead of the data attached to messages, you are probably out of luck.  At least from the standpoint of duplicating behavior by mimicking input.

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) is the only reliable way to accomplish this without interfering with the user.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? It sounds like you want to copy the input of one of the notepads. For keystrokes, maybe you could try to install the keyboard hook, and then monitor the keyboard and of that notepad window, and write to other files manually.